# What is the name of this PDE $\partial_t u = F(u) - \mathcal{L}_{\mathcal{V}}u$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-dynamics, lie-derivative

I've come across the following PDE
$$
\partial_t u = F(u) - \mathcal{L}_{\mathcal{V}} u
$$
where the solution $u : \mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is a vector field in space $\mathbb{R}^3$ and time $\mathbb{R}$, which evolves according to a nonlinear function $F :\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ and the Lie derivative $\mathcal{L}_{\mathcal{V}}$ defined with respect to a smooth vector field $\mathcal{V}$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$. Does anyone know what this type of PDE this is called?

Comment: I'm confused by the equation $\partial_tu=F(u)-\nabla u$: $u$ is a scalar function, so $\partial_tu$ is also a scalar function; however, $F(u)$ and $\nabla u$ are both vector-valued functions. How can a scalar equal to a vector?

Comment: My mistake, I have changed u to a vector field

Comment: Now $\nabla u$ is a $3\times3$ matrix, so the same problem appears…

Comment: Thanks for this; I realise the gradient actually doesn't work as a special case, so I've removed this from the question for now.